# How do I fix Invalid Decimal literal?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm making a game in the turtle module. Right now I making 'cells' which are my board pieces. I'm making a cell with a swirl inside of it. I need to move to a specific position on the cell's side. For my spiral, I use the code `circle(2.5+t, 45)`. I want to move back and then I can go to the side of the cell.

I've tried to just reverse the code: `circle(-2.5t, 45)` and then move back to the side, but this line comes up with the error: `Invalid decimal literal.` How do I fix this?

Comment: The reverse of `2.5+t` is not `-2.5t`, just fix that typo.

Comment: `2.5+t` means "the result of adding 2.5 and t". What result are you looking for when you write `-2.5t`?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the "Invalid decimal literal" error in your code, you need to make a small adjustment. The expression -2.5t is not a valid syntax in Python. Instead, you should use -2.5 * t, where * represents multiplication. Here's the corrected code:
circle(-2.5 * t, 45)
By multiplying -2.5 with t, you ensure that the value is calculated correctly. Now you should be able to move back and proceed to the side of the cell without encountering the error.

Comment: If the first step of the calculation was an addition (`2.5+t`), do you think that the multiplication `-2.5 * t` would "reverse the code" as OP says they want to do?